# make: Nothing to be done for 'all', Make file generated by automake and autoconf

Tags: linux, makefile, autoconf, automake

we have a lot of post in stack for error "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'". But most of them generated manually Make file.

Amazingly today I want compile a library and ran automake and generated "Makefile" successfully. but after tried to "make" I get error Nothing to be done for 'all'.
If it is possible please try it. Probably compiling will become filed because it is for ARM not for x86-64.If you can start compiling, it shows you can solve issue.

first download file from [Here](http://wget%20http://www.nxp.com/lgfiles/NMG/MAD/YOCTO//libfslcodec-4.0.8.bin)

Extract file by this command and you can see a directory will make.
It is official "Freescale" library for IMX6Q.

```
./libfslcodec-4.0.8.bin --auto-accept –force
```

Then

```
cd libfslcodec-*

./autogent.sh --prefix=/usr --enable-fhw --enable-vpu
```

Now Make file Generated.Let's try make, so you can see error:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

I tried on Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, 16.04 and all of the return Same results also I tried `make -nd` but I did't understand issue.

How can I solve issue? 
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any desire to download random stuff from the internet and run it on my system.  If you want help you'll have to do enough investigation on your own to be able to provide sufficient details here that we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I assume you've checked the obvious things: (a) there's no file named `all` in the directory, and (b) there's an actual `Makefile` (or `makefile`) file in the directory where you're running.  If that's true you'll need to show us the definition of the `all:` target in the makefile and figure out why it doesn't have any dependencies that haven't been built.